# Dependency on a remote file in make

Tags: makefile

I have a situation where I need to execute a rule in make depending on a remote file. This is an example of what I'm trying to do (the actual Makefile is a lot more complicated in ways that aren't relevant here):

```
URL = http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico

stackoverflow.png: favico.ico modified | check_modified
    convert favicon.ico $@

check_modified: modified
    @echo Icon was modified. Downloading.
    rm -f favicon.ico
    wget $(URL)

.PHONY: check_modified

favico.ico: check_modified

modified:
    touch -d "`wget --spider -S $(URL) 2>&1 | sed -n 's/.*Modified: //p'`" $@
```

The idea is:

- The rule to build `modified` should *always* be run. The function of that rule is to change the modification time of the file to be the same as the modification time of what the URL points to.
- After that, I want `modified` to behave normally in terms of dependencies. If `modified` is more recent than `favicon.ico`, I want to retrieve the new file and then let the dependency on it cause the target file to be remade.

As a wrinkle, in some applications, I have to retrieve the file manually. In those cases, I want to just have a rule that fires and tells me to manually download the file, but that doesn't otherwise affect building the target. As an example, if the source image that I'm converting were behind a site login, I'd need to manually login to the site and download it to a fixed location and then rerun make.

Everything I've tried either:

- Fails to check the URL if the target is up to date, or
- Always checks the URL and rebuilds the target, even if `modified` is not more recent than the target.

Any words of wisdom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is probably that make builds the dependency graph before running any recipe. So, when your `modified` tag file is created / updated, it is too late for make to consider its last modification date and use it to decide whether other targets shall be built or not.

Your first observed behaviour (*fails to check the URL if the target is up to date*) probably corresponds to attempts where you did not use the `.PHONY` special target. As soon as `modified` has been created, make always considers it as up-to-date because it has no prerequisites and thus cannot be outdated.

The second behaviour (*always checks the URL and rebuilds the target, even if modified is not more recent than the target*) corresponds to what you posted: `check_modified` is a prerequisite of the `.PHONY` special target, which forces make to always consider it as outdated. `stackoverflow.png` and `favico.ico`, directly or not, depend on `check_modified` and are thus also always considered as outdated.

One option to solve your problem would be to use a recursive, two-passes, make invocation. On a first run make would build the `all` phony target (always), update a `modified` tag file, and then invoke itself again to build other targets that have the tag file as prerequisite and are outdated. As, for the second invocation, make rebuilds its dependency graph, it will take the last modification date of the tag file into account. Something like:

```
URL = http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico

.PHONY: all

all:
    touch -d "`wget --spider -S $(URL) 2>&1 | sed -n 's/.*Modified: //p'`" modified
    $(MAKE) stackoverflow.ico

stackoverflow.ico: modified 
    @echo Icon was modified. Downloading.; \
    rm -f favicon.ico; \
    wget $(URL); \
    convert favicon.ico $@
```

**Explanations:**

- I replaced your conversion to `png` by a useless conversion to `ico` because the `favicon.ico` icon of SO is composite and its conversion to `png` creates two files instead of one, named `stackoverflow-0.png` and `stackoverflow-1.png`, which uselessly complicates things.
- `all` is a true phony target and the default goal so, each time you invoke `make` (or `make all`), it is built. It first updates the `modified` tag file and then invokes make again to build `stackoverflow.ico`.
- The second make invocation does nothing if `stackoverflow.ico` is more recent than `modified`, else it downloads and converts.

Your second question (get a message about required manual operations) is completely different and simpler to solve. Let's first define a message and echo it in the file's recipe:

```
define DIY_message
Dear user, you should first:
- do this
- and that.
Unless you know it is useless, of course.
endef
export DIY_message

the_remote_file:
    @echo "$$DIY_message"
```

The message will be printed if make is invoked with this goal (`make the_remote_file`) or with a goal that somehow depends on `the_remote_file` and either:

- `the_remote_file` does not exist,
- or `the_remote_file` exists but is out-of-date with respect to its prerequisites (if you declared prerequisites for it),
- or `the_remote_file` is a prerequisite of `.PHONY`.

Note: using an intermediate make variable assigned by a `define-endef` makes things easier for formatted multi-lines messages.